# What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

What is the significance of the ProjectTypeGuids  tag in a visual studio project?? When I created a WPF application, i am seeing two GUIDs in here.

```
{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}**
```

Does these represent WPF and Windows type of applications?

If I create my own project type (.myproj) that has .xaml and .cs files, what should I fill in this ProjectTypeGuids tags? Should I also need to fill the ProjectType tag?

It would also be better if someone differentiate the ProjectType and ProjectTypeGuids*tags.

Comment: Related post - [Visual Studio project type guids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802198/465053)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

- `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` is the GUID for C# project
- `{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548}` is for project in WPF flavor package

So your `ProjectTypeGuids` is for a WPF C# project.

You could see the meaning of the different GUID in the register :

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Projects` for ProjectTypeGuids
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages` for packages reference by some project

### Some ProjectTypeGuids

```
Windows (C#)           {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
Windows (VB.NET)       {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
Windows (Visual C++)   {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Web Application        {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Web Site               {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
WCF                    {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
WPF                    {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
XNA (Windows)          {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
XNA (XBox)             {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
XNA (Zune)             {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}
Silverlight            {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
ASP.NET MVC            {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
ASP.NET MVC 4          {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
Test                   {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
Solution Folder        {2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}
```

Comment: Okay, now if I wanna create my own project (.myproj) with .xaml files in it, should I flavor the project file with that GUID ??

Comment: Do you really need a new project type if it is a project with .xaml and .cs files? If you do, I think you'll have to use a different Guid.

Comment: yeah, i need a custom extension for my projects and I am trying to use MPF for VS2010

Comment: To use custom projects with wpf/other flavors, we need to use FlavoredProjectBase

Comment: Thanks this helped me when merging ASP.NET MVC into an existing ASP.NET WebForms project and I wanted the content menu's hanging off the new Controllers, Views, etc folders.

Comment: These registry keys don't exist for me under 'local machine' but under 'current user'

Comment: Cam you please link to the source of this list of GUIDs? Any official reference (will be helpful for giving to others). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Meligy For the list of GUIDs, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19111363/293099).

Comment: Why the heck would they use a GUID for this? Couldn't they just, you know, use "Windows (C#)" to signify a C# project instead of some obtuse GUID that you have to look up in the Windows registry of all places.

Comment: There is a pretty thorough list of available projecttypeguids over here: http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Comment: For Visual studio 2015 GUIDs are located in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Projects and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Packages

Comment: On a 64-bit machine you need to look in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ otherwise the paths are correct. The editing of this answer no longer works (Stack Overflow thinks there is improperly formatted code?)

Comment: The list mentioned by @FrederikStruck-Schøning is now a GitHub repo at [/JamesW75/visual-studio-project-type-guid](https://github.com/JamesW75/visual-studio-project-type-guid).

Answer (score 24):

**From [MZ-Tools: List of known project type Guids](https://web.archive.org/web/20210726052235/http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx):**

Every Visual Studio project has a project type (Windows project, Smart Device project, Web Site project, etc.) and in some cases more than one type (subtypes or flavors).

Every project type is identified by a unique Guid, so every project has one or more project type Guids.

Project type Guids are stored generally in the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

But for some special projects (such as some database projects) and projects lacking a file (such as Web Site projects), the project type is stored also in the solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "SqlServerProject1", "SqlServerProject1.vbproj", "{BE5F0BE0-93CD-4FCE-A853-9096A442DF1B}"
EndProject
```

The project type Guids are stored in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\Projects`. However, not all the Guids stored in that registry key are actual project types. Some of them are used only to provide project templates (for C# and VB.NET projects) and others have other purposes. The following table lists known project type Guids.

```
Project Type Description                 Project Type Guid

Windows (C#)                             {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
Windows (VB.NET)                         {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
Windows (Visual C++)                     {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Web Application                          {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Web Site                                 {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
Distributed System                       {F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C}
Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)   {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)    {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
Visual Database Tools                    {C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387}
Database                                 {A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124}
Database (other project types)           {4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8}
Test                                     {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
Legacy (2003) Smart Device (C#)          {20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32}
Legacy (2003) Smart Device (VB.NET)      {CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8}
Smart Device (C#)                        {4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884}
Smart Device (VB.NET)                    {68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F}
Workflow (C#)                            {14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}
Workflow (VB.NET)                        {D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8}
Deployment Merge Module                  {06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267}
Deployment Cab                           {3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A}
Deployment Setup                         {978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}
Deployment Smart Device Cab              {AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}
Visual Studio Tools for Apps (VSTA)      {A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107}
Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)    {BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}
SharePoint Workflow                      {F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90}
XNA (Windows)                            {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
XNA (XBox)                               {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
XNA (Zune)                               {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}
SharePoint (VB.NET)                      {EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484}
SharePoint (C#)                          {593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2}
Silverlight                              {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
ASP.NET MVC 1.0                          {603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}
ASP.NET MVC 2.0                          {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
ASP.NET MVC 3.0                          {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
ASP.NET MVC 4.0                          {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
```

Comment: I can't find these guids from the registry location under windows 8, does MS move them to another place?

Comment: @Vincent These GUIDs are stored in the executable files of Visual Studio and related products somewhere, I guess.

Comment: @Vincent: On 64-bit Windows, the project type GUIDs are stored in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\Projects`.

Comment: There is a pretty thorough list of available projecttypeguids over here: http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Answer (score 12):

A thread at msdn has already been started and a lot has been discussed out there. If anybody is interested to know about this, check [What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/d9d05cdc-96a1-4044-95d8-a4f8885a660a)

> ProjectTypeGuids is used by Visual Studio for project aggregation. In
>   your example you have a WPF  (represented by
>   **60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548**) C# project (represented by
>   **FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC**).
>
> If you have a custom project type working with both .xaml and .cs you
>   should try to add your custom project guid (specified by your project
>   factory GUID) as below:
>
> `<ProjectTypeGuids>{YourProjectFactoryClassGUID};{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
>   </ProjectTypeGuids>`

Comment: It is sad that nowhere (including the pages shared by you) explains clearly why the  projecttypeguids are needed. Someone from MS explained on the page you shared that the projecttypeguids are only for project aggregation. What does that mean? Who knows.

Comment: @Cary I just noticed that when you omit ProjectTypeGuids for web app, Visual Studio does not know how to debug your web app. So it is not completely meaningless.