# Why can't I add certain file types to VS2010 projects?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to add a WPF ResourceDictionary to a C# project that was created a while ago. The project was not originally a WPF project, but now I need to include some WPF resources in it.

When I right click the project and select "Add", ResourceDictionary is not an option. Even if I open the Modal dialog box and navigate to where the ResourceDictionary type should be (along side the other WPF types), it is not present.

Also, when I manually add a XAML file that has ResourceDictionary syntax to the project, I can't programmatically load it using WPF Application.Load(uri) syntax, so I feel VS2010 is preventing me from adding the file for a reason.

How can I make my project "able" to have a ResourceDictionary added without recreating the entire project from scratch as a WPF project and re-adding every file from scratch?

Additionally, what defines the file types that can be added to projects so I can avoid similar problems in the future? Hopefully it's something simple like a line I need to add to my AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: What was the project created as? I'm not really surprised you can't add a WPF element to a non WPF project.

Comment: That should be filed as a bug at Microsoft right? It's perfectly valid to create a WPF window on a Class Project.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Close the project. Create a new project that is of the type of WPF project you would have used. Then open the new .csproj file in notepad. Find the `ProjectTypeGuids` element. Copy those GUIDs to clipboard. Open your existing .csproj file in notepad. Append those GUIDs into this file's `ProjectTypeGuids` element. (Check for dupes.) Reload your project in Visual Studio. You should be able to add all the WPF file types now.

PS: I haven't done this with WPF specifically, but I have with other project types and it has worked without issue.

I believe the GUIDS are the same for everyone so the values you need should be: `{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` ... this should save you the step of creating a new project.

Comment: My csproj didn't even have a ProjectTypeGuids. I added this and it works:   <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: Not sure if you can simply add a new `<PropertyGroup>`, but one of my existing projects listed `<ProjectTypeGuids>` under the first `<PropertyGroup>...<FileAlignment>` element.

Comment: For reference: here is a [compiled list](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs) with a lot of different project GUIDs. It contains the mentioned GUIDs as well.

Comment: Edited the answer to account for a situation when there is no `ProjectTypeGuids` element in the existing project(Class Library, for example). Needs to be approved, though.

Comment: Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911651/6908282) to know the significance of `ProjectTypeGuids`

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to create a new WPF project and copy everything across. If it is a very large project (and you are feeling adventurous) you might open the XML of the project files (Unload the project, then edit the original csproj file in XML)

[image]

Then copy across the `ItemGroup` sections, and ensure the corresponding source files exist under the new project directory. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a blank WPF project and then diff the .csproj files (they're just plain XML) for that and your project to see what differences there are - apart from the file lists and the odd compiler setting, you may well find a GUID or other entry that identifies the type of the project, which you will be able to copy/paste across to "upgrade" your project (after taking a backup of your existing project file of course!)

Alternatively, you can copy and paste the file/folder XML (carefully) between the csproj files to quickly "rebuild the entire project from scratch", so this needn't be something to be afraid of doing.