# Can't find ResourceDictionary in Add New Item Window

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

When I create a new WPF project I can find ResourceDictionary in Add New Item Window.
But I've another Project I can't find that and I don't know why.
[image: Only UserControl but no ResourceDictionary]

UPDATE：
The project was for .net 3.5 originally, but now it also has a version for .net 4.0. It means there're two .sln files (one for 3.5 and the other for 4.0) both for the same project.

Comment: You cut out the important part of the project. What .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: The project originally is of version 3.5, and now it also has a .sln for version 4.0. It means, there're two .sln files for the same project now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I hope you realize this shouldn't stop you since you can easily add any file you want to a project, either from your file system or by copying it from another project.  The Add New Item window is just for convenience.

Secondly, when you added the new project to your solution, which project template did you choose?  The project template determines the initial set of referenced assemblies that project has.  A WPF project makes references to the WPF libraries (WindowsBase, PresentationCore, etc.).

Visual Studio uses your referenced assemblies to generate the possible items you see in the Add New Items dialog.

So I'm assuming you added some other type of project, such as a basic Class Library.  You could manually add the references to the WPF assemblies using the Add Reference dialog.  Or you could re-create the project as a WPF Custom Control Library.

Comment: Thanks. Acctually I did it as you say but I made a mistake at another place.

Comment: Actually, this is misleading: "Visual Studio uses your referenced assemblies to generate the possible items you see in the Add New Items dialog." It has nothing to do with what assemblies you reference. VS adds special GUIDs to projects created as WPF projects. Adding these in your project file will enable to you add a ResourceDictionary. Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544137/why-cant-i-add-certain-file-types-to-vs2010-projects

Answer (score 35):

Add the following line to Project.csproj

> ```
>     <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
> ```

It should be a child of the `<PropertyGroup>` tag, like so:

> ```
>     <Project>
>       <PropertyGroup>
>         ....
>         <ProjectTypeGuids>{guids};{go};{here}</ProjectTypeGuids>
>         ...
>       </PropertyGroup>
>     ...
>     </Project>
> ```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi) does a good job of explaining why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Close the project. Create a new project that is of the type of WPF project you would have used(or use existing one). Then open the .csproj file of WPF project in text editor. Find the `ProjectTypeGuids` element.

Open your existing .csproj file in notepad. See if it has `ProjectTypeGuids` element. If it does, append GUID(without the `ProjectTypeGuids`) from WPF project in your existing project. If your existing .csproj file doesn't have `ProjectTypeGuids` element in it, copy `ProjectTypeGuids` from your WPF project together with GUID and paste it in your existing project in the first `PropertyGroup` element.

Reload your project in Visual Studio. You should be able to add all the WPF file types now.

I believe the GUIDS are the same for everyone so the values you need should be: `{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` ... this should save you the step of creating a new project.

So if you have a class library project, just add

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

To the first `PropertyGroup` element in your .csproj file.