# Cannot add a page to my project

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2012

One of my projects in Visual Studio is a WPF project.

I have the default files which are created plus 2 classes which I've added and a couple of folders.

[image]

The issue I have is, when I try to add a Window to my View folder, I can't as I don't have the option of Window (or page for that matter).

[image]

As you can see, for some reason and despite my application being created as a WPF project it now thinks it's a WinForms project.

How do I revert/change it from WinForms to a WPF project?

---

**EDIT**
Please note, I am using Visual Studio 2012 Premium.

If I add a new WPF project, I do get the options of Page/Window etc, so this fault is project specific.

Based upon the comments, this is the screen I get when I click on Add New Item (sorry I can't fit in the entire list)

[image]

And this is the view of the WPF menu

[image]

Comment: How about if you try Add - New Item - WPF - Window ?

Comment: The only WPF related item (using the Search Installed Templates or the WPF menu item) is User Control (WPF). Now, I added another WPF project and I can add Page / Window so the fault is specific to this project.

Comment: You probably are using a limited VS express version or somehow removed the WPF wizards... guessing.

Comment: What are your options when you select New Item?

Comment: @DaveRook click WPF from the left side choices and it should limit the almost unlimited options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I add certain file types to VS2010 projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544137/why-cant-i-add-certain-file-types-to-vs2010-projects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the proj file by hand and add ProjectTypeGuids for C# and WPF. It should be something like this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

After the project is reloaded you should have normal options for a WPF project type.

More info about ProjectTypeGuids [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi).

Comment: Well, this fixes it but do you have any experience as to why this happened? PC glitch / Visual Studio having a 'senior moment' or me changing something by mistake?

Comment: I have no clue how it happened. Since if you create a new WPF project everything is fine and i'm not aware of any way to change this beside editing the proj file i guess something weird happened there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I added this under one of the existing `<PropertyGroup>` tags and it worked.