# Why can't I add a window or page to a WPF project in VS2019 V16.5.2

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF/C# project in VS2019. Since upgrading from v16.4 to v16.5.2 I am unable to add a new window or page to the project. I right click the project, choose Add.., and then select either "Window (WPF)..." or "Page (WPF)..." from the list. In either case I am presented with an "Add new item" dialog containing only C# items, no XAML. I have tried creating a new WPF project but I still get the same behaviour. Has anyone else experience this?

Comment: [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626431/6908282) - where you can only see "User Control (WPF)" in the "Add New Item" window and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure you selected WPF on the left. If it isn't there, you will need to run Visual Studio installer and check if you WPF installed - maybe it got lost with the update.

Also, if you by any chance migrated your project to .NET Core, then I think that VS does not recognize the projects as WPF

Comment: Krzysztof,thanks for the suggestion. I re-ran the installer and checked that WPF was included.After a restart, the problem has been resolved.