# Removing Project Type GUID <ProjectTypeGuid>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, sharepoint

I was getting annoyed with one of the problems where I get this error

> "The project type is not supported by this installation".

After searching a lot I came across a blog:

http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2009/05/project-type-is-not-supported-by-this.html

Following this I deleted a line in my csproj file which contained a tag `<ProjectTypeGuid>` and I got the problem solved. But I'm scared to Check-in my changes and afraid that it would break.

Just need to know the consequences of removing this tag..? Is it fine ?

Comment: You might want to check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/d9d05cdc-96a1-4044-95d8-a4f8885a660a) post about the significanse of the project GUID tag.

Comment: Thanks Bojan.. I went through this but its merely a definition but what I actually want to know if removing this tag will create any problem while deploying (basically its a Sharepoint control).

Comment: It is used to identify the technology used, language and/or visual studio version etc. So if you deploy only a .dll it shouldn't cause you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely missing the Visual Studio Extensions for Windows SharePoint Services 1.3 (SP2007) or the optional SharePoint Tools in the VS2010 installation (SP2010), **do not modify your project or else your team members won't be able to deploy/package it**.

Comment: Thanks Aquino.. this is working perfectly fine. Thanks for the exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only visual studio uses that property. It might cause problems for others on your team. You could always check it in, but roll it back if it makes the problems worse.

Answer (score 1):

One use by Visual Studio is population of the "Add New Item" dialog.
I'd say removing this tag WILL cause problems for the team.
One GUID identifies the language, another the type of project(class library, executable, etc).
See this question for more details.
[What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi)