# Determining a VS2010 WebService project from .csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

I'm writing some PS to inspect .csproj files (for enforcing an SCM check-in policy)

Is the following check sufficient to determine if a .csproj is a WebService project?

```
    # Check for WebProjectProperties (indicates project is a Web Service)
if ($xmldata.Project.ProjectExtensions.VisualStudio.FlavorProperties.WebProjectProperties -ne $null)
{
    $isWebService = $true
}
```

The only alternative I've seen is parsing the [Project.PropertyGroup.ProjectTypeGuids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi) - but that seems overkill if this element is always set for a WS as well.

Comment: I would think the project guid is the best check.  Its guaranteed.

Comment: Re. that "guarantee", I was hoping to find some MSDN article with a list of the ProjectTypeGuids, but the best one I've found so far is: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx  - anybody know of  anything more definitive (e.g. published by MS?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging a bit further, I'm (mostly) convinced.  I've added this Dictionary:

```
# Visual Studio ProjectTypeGuid keys - store in a constant dictionary
# Courtesy of http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx
New-Variable -Name ProjTypeMap -Option Constant -Value @{
"FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC" = "Windows (C#)";
"F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F" = "Windows (VB.NET)";
"8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942" = "Windows (Visual C++)";
"349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21" = "Web Application";
"E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A" = "Web Site";
"F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C" = "Distributed System";
"3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699" = "Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)";
"60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548" = "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)";
"C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387" = "Visual Database Tools";
"A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124" = "Database";
"4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8" = "Database (other project types)";
"3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB" = "Test";
"20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32" = "Legacy (2003) Smart Device (C#)";
"CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8" = "Legacy (2003) Smart Device (VB.NET)";
"4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884" = "Smart Device (C#)";
"68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F" = "Smart Device (VB.NET)";
"14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079" = "Workflow Foundation 3.0 (C#)";
"D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8" = "Workflow Foundation 3.0 (VB.NET)";
"32f31d43-81cc-4c15-9de6-3fc5453562b6" = "Workflow Foundation 4.0";
"06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267" = "Deployment Merge Module";
"3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A" = "Deployment Cab";
"978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA" = "Deployment Setup";
"AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55" = "Deployment Smart Device Cab";
"A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107" = "Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA)";
"BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33" = "Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)";
"F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90" = "SharePoint Workflow";
"6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596" = "XNA (Windows)";
"2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2" = "XNA (XBox)";
"D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433" = "XNA (Zune)";
"EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484" = "SharePoint (VB.NET)";
"593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2" = "SharePoint (C#)";
"A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B" = "Silverlight"
}
```

and look-up any ProjectTypeGuids encountered.  This did flush out one more WebApp than just testing on Project.ProjectExtensions.VisualStudio.FlavorProperties.WebProjectProperties, so it is more robust.

Comment: Added the guid for 4.0 workflows.  The ones you listed were for 3.0 workflows.  That article was kinda old, so there might be different guids for solutions targeting 4.0.  The only way to get the correct ones is to go through every template and create a new project.  You can then scan the files for the guids.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like one could also enumerate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Projects\{GUID} and get a reasonable description from the (Default) string, without having to create one of everyting.  I do wish SO recognized .ps1 language for syntax highlighting!

Answer (score 1):

The WebProjectProperties section also exists for web application projects.

The distinction seems to be whether the app.config (probably web.config too?) contains (non-empty) configuration/system.serviceModel/services/service/host sections.

Comment: Thanks for this, this looks way simpler than maintaining a list of guids.

Answer (score 0):

This list has been very helpful ! Thx a lot.
I was only missing this Guid:

"EF7E3281-CD33-11D4-8326-00C04FA0CE8D" = "BizTalk"