# Did VS2013 incorrectly upgrade my project files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I had a solution that included both an ASP.NET MVC web project and a WebAPI project.  The solution was created originally with VS2012, but I recently upgraded it to VS2013.

I just noticed when going to add a controller that I'm not getting the correct options in the right click menu.  For instance if I go to the web project and right click the controllers folder, the option to add a controller isn't there.  Instead I have add WebAPI controller.  It's exactly the opposite for the WebAPI project.

Things seem to build and run ok so far, but it's going to be a pain manually adding things and I'm wondering if something else might break.  Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that project type is different in your csproj. Take a look at this question:
[What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi)

Here is what I have on my machine for c# asp.net mvc project:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Take a look at your guids and see what they mean.
You could see the meaning of the different GUID in the register :

> •HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Projects for
> ProjectTypeGuids
>
> •HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages for
> packages reference by some project

Comment: Finally got a chance to check, the guids match yours and also checked against another project I created in VS2013 (which works correctly.)  Any other ideas?