# The project type is not supported by this installation while opening mobile device program

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

I have downloaded one program for the windows mobile 6.5 from net.while i am opening that in visual studio 2008 .i am getting this error:

```
the project type is not supported by this installation
```

my projecttypeGuid is like this:

```
 <ProjectTypeGuids>{68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

what is the problem? is there anything i have to download and install.Please help me to find out.  no correct answer i haven't got

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi)

This is SmartDevice VB.NET ProjectType.

Do you have any Windows Mobile SDK installed?

See also http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Comment: sir so what i can do now? anything i have to install? how i can open this project?

Comment: yes sir..I have downloaded windows mobile 6 Profassional SDK

Comment: SmartDevice projects are NOT supported in Visual Studio Express. Which VS are you running? If everything fails, create a new SmartDevice VB project and copy over all files from the existing project into the new project (use the same name!) and then load the existing files into the project...