# Project template type determination in visual studio after its creation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution in visual studio with multiple projects under it. Is there any way to determine which type of project it is?

Is it a unit Test project or a coded UI test project ..? One way to determine is by the icon of project but I noticed that they have similar icons for the Coded UI project and Unit Test Project.

[image: Solution view]
[image: Project view]

Comment: Every project has a project type id. That can be found in the .sln file. See https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs for a lookup table

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi

Comment: Thanks Peter..!! While looking for GUID in csproj file i got a tag in it which says about project type.  TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType