# Project Type GUID for ASP.NET Website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, webforms

My ASP.NET solution has a Website project (with no csproj file). I need to know the project type GUID. How do I find it?

Comment: Is any update? please check if  the following answers work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have known it is a web site project, we can refer to the list in the following link to find the correspond project type GUID.

[Visual Studio Project Type GUIDs](https://github.com/VISTALL/visual-studio-project-type-guids/blob/master/README.md)

For example:

```
Web Site    {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
```

I create a web project and open the sln file, I find they are the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, How to check this value in the solution?

Comment: @VK9217, Please open the sln file with the notepad, then you can find the above new picture with the correspond project type GUID.

Answer (score 0):

The csproj file is not shown in the solution by default if you're using VS. You can try right clicking on the project, [Open Folder in File Explorer] & check for the csproj file there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the projectType GUID in the solution (.sln) file. You could also check the link [What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi) and see if it helps.