# How to create a Nuget package from Unit Test project

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nuget, xunit

I have a useful extension for Xunit which I use through various .NET 3.1 projects. I want to build a NuGet package to easily distribute it.
But when I add a Xunit dependency to my Visual Studio project it is immediately marked as Unit Test project and stops generating .nupkg file (I have "Generate NuGet package on build" checked in the project settings).
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting unnecessary dependencies like "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" after that my project stopped being a unit test project. Then I switched Xunit dependency to xunit.extensibility.core which is supposed to be used especially for extensions.
Finally, Visual Studion successfully generated .nupkg file on build