# Why wcf service is not discovered when it's created in "Windows Class Library" project?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I added **Wcf Service Library** project to solution and it created 2 classes (`Service1`, `IService1`) and config file. Now I want to add that service to my **Console** project in the same solution. I click "Add Service Reference -> Discover" and it finds that service.

When I create **Windows Class Library** project and create there the same example as in just created **Wcf Service Library** project and then try to add it as reference to my **Console** project, so clicking on **Discover** doesn't return anything. Why?

What is the difference when I create **Wcf Service Library** project or **Windows Class Library** project and create there the same as in **Wcf Service Library**?

**Edited**

The `Discover` works only if the service is in **Wcf Service Library**. But once I move to other project (**Console**, **Class Library**) the `Discover` doesn't find it anymore. Why?

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**Service1.cs**

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**IService.cs**

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Discover.  Service library is a class library with some plumbing added.  Know I built a WCF Service starting with Class Library and it works.  Three projects.  The Service (class), Service Host (console), and Service Client (console).  The client needs the host running.  Are you sure the service is running?

Comment: the service is running. I run the service by running it from its bin/Debug directory and then trying to add Service Reference.

Comment: Still broken?  Please post the code where start the host.

Comment: this will help you- http://tilr.blogspot.com/2014/06/create-wcf-service-in-class-project.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some checking I came to conclusion that only if you create **WCF Service Library** you can create client with `Add Service Reference->Discover` button without running the host explicitly and it will find the service.

If you create **Class Library** project that will have then your service files so you cannot create client with `Add Service Reference->Discover` if the service is not hosted(is not running). You should run the host and only after it put the address of service in **Address** bar and press **Go**

Comment: See comments.  "Are you sure the service is running?"  "Yes the service is running."

Comment: @Blam, I'm not talking adding service reference by writing it in address bar, but I when I click `Discover` button

Comment: Yes, Discover button, so?  The point is the service needs to be running.  The first comment was is the is the service running to which you responded yes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like WCF options shows up only when you create a project using wcf project template, if you have an existing project (class library) you could convert it by adding this in the first property group more discussion [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bbc6d1f6-15f1-40b6-a96d-ab8a9fb52048/cant-discover-a-wcf-serevice-into-my-solution?forum=wcf)

In the first  section, add the following line:
{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

Answer (score 0):

turn on in project properties `Wcf options` `start host`

Comment: It doesn't have such project property. It's regular Windows Class Library

Comment: recreate as WcfClassLibrary or start host manual, in console aplication for example

Comment: but why it happens?  What `Wcf options start host` has to do with my question? Even if I uncheck  `Wcf options start host` in "Wcf Service Library" project it's still discovered.

Comment: so, why `Discover` works only if wcf service created with **Wcf Service Library** project?

Comment: your project not started or you delete mex, check this

Comment: I don't delete nothing. I copy those files from that project to **Windows Class Library** that's all

Comment: @it's exactly as Visual Studio generated it. I didn't changed anything

Comment: someone application host wcf?

Comment: yes, even if convert **Windows Class Library** to **Console Application** and host the service there the Discover still doesn't find. Try it yourself and you'll see.

Comment: no, don't convert, you must start host `var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProviderServer));
            host.Open();`

Comment: I think **Dsicover** works only if the project where the files of the service is **WCF Service Library** because if I convert **Windows Class Library** to **WCF Service Library** according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759307/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-convert-from-a-class-library-to-a-wcf the **Discover** finds the service!

Comment: @legion, that exactly what I did in `Main` method

Comment: WCF Service Library host wcf usually, that's why you cad discover it

Comment: may be you forget create app config in your hist application?

Comment: no, I don't forget. I'm saying I didn't changed ANYTHING! just copied **ALL** files to **WIndows Class Library**

Comment: WIndows Class Library host wcf, any other project - no, if your idn't changed ANYTHING, it will not be work

Comment: So, when I click Discover button **Wcf Service Library** host it? Usually when it's hosted visual studio popups the host window in taskbar near the clock. But this is not the case when I click Discover button. So, you say the VS make **Wcf Service Library** host service internally and we don't see this?

Comment: popups the host window in taskbar near the clock aviable only in WCF Service Library

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Go to Debug -> Start without debugging. This should start host and client applications. Then go to client and add service reference. In other words, the service has to be running

Comment: I tried this, but didnt work for me. Only way I found to add service reference was by inputting the url manually, from an instance of the service running through service host without debugging.